# Using re.findAll for decimal numbers

Tags: python, string, numbers, decimal, findall

I did use re.findAll to extract decimal number from a string like this:

```
size = "Koko33,5 m²"

numbers = re.findall("\d+\,*\d+", size)

print(numbers) = ['33,5']
```

Then I was trying to get only number 33,5 out of that ['33,5'].

And by guess I did this :

```
numbers = re.findall("\d+\,*\d+", size)[0]
```

And it worked. But I don't understand why it worked?

I'm new to programming so every help is good :)

Comment: findall returns a list, and by doing `re.findall("\d+\,*\d+", size)[0]` you get the first element of the list

Answer (score 2):

It works because it finds the pattern where the is a number, then a comma, then another number.

`\d` gets a number, `+` gets the previous expression (`\d`) to get all the continuous same letters, then `\,` just finds the comma, then `*` matches between zero and unlimited times then there is another `\d+`.

The last thing, the slicing part (`[0]`), gets the first matched pattern (in this case there is only one).

[More explanation](https://regex101.com/r/BZhncj/1)

Answer (score 1):

You guessed well.

```
\d+  Find 1 or more numbers (1,2,3...)
,*   Find 0, 1 or more commas
\d+  Find 1 or more numbers (1,2,3...)
```

The pattern should find 33,5 or 999,123.  Any "number comma number" pattern.

Best source on Regex that I have found is "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl.